# Loading player position from file but player object not at right position sometimes

Tags: unity, json

In my current project I am developing a game saving system and I have encountered a problem where in some cases when I save the game and re-load it the player will not be loaded in at the correct position.

I've printed the position that is loaded in from file to the console to see if it's being changed and it's not.

Is there anything i'm not seeing?

For reference here's the two methods I use when loading the game:

```
    public void LoadData() {
    if (File.Exists(filename)) {
        byte[] soupBackIn = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        string jsonFromFile = encryption.Decrypt(soupBackIn, JSON_ENCRYPTION_KEY);    
        copy = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveData>(jsonFromFile);
        print(copy.playerPosition);
        DataToLoad();
    }
}

private void DataToLoad() {
    player.transform.position = copy.playerPosition;
    player.transform.rotation = copy.playerRot;
    player.playerHealth = copy.playerHealth;
    player.agility = copy.agility;
    player.attack = copy.attack;
    player.defense = copy.defense;
    player.strength = copy.strength;

    for (int i = 0; i < copy.inventory.Count; i++) {
        inv.AddItem(copy.inventory[i].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noting the rollback. We dont mark the question, itself, as solved. Instead, mark your answer as accepted. You will need to wait a couple of days before you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried I just didn't want people to waste their time clicking on this question but that's fine and noted for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a NavMeshAgent attached to my player from a previous prototype of a movement type for the game and it was interfering with where the player was positioned.

Comment: You can also mark this as the answer ;)